# Mongodb date stored as Epoch

Tags: mongodb

So for some reason Mongodb has stored date as Epoch `1593236606706`

However now I need to query it. because I need to get the month and year from each of these.

I am wondering how do you ask mongodb to convert Epoch to Date?

I am trying the following

```
{ $convert: { input: "history.starttime", to: "date" } }
```

[image: MongodB Data]

I have also tried

```
$addField:{
      convertedDate: { $toDate: "$history.starttime" }
 }
```

but no I think because I am not able to call the sub array?

Also tried this

```
 {
      history:{
        convertedDate: { $toDate:"$history[starttime]" }
        }
   }
```

but that just puts it in the correct sub array - still can't grab start date from that subarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$history"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "d": {
        $convert: {
          input: "$history.key",
          to: "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You need to have it part of `$project` after `unwinding` it as it is an array.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fh1EakUEHlN)

You can regroup it after project if you want to bring the original structure using `$group`.

Comment: I am getting asked for 

{
  path: path,
  includeArrayIndex: 'string',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: boolean
}

Comment: Can you paste your document as text?

Answer (score 1):

Example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/sNG9Wh2HeI4

You need to $unwind your array first and then do the conversion. Regroup it at the end